# Chrome does not render dates correctly

Tags: macos, google-chrome

For some reason, my Chrome browser does not correctly render dates when I look at something under the news tab of a Google search.

[image]

As you can see, the spacing for the date is "15Dec.,2015" when it obviously should be something like "15 Dec., 2015". This doesn't happen anywhere else (for example, when I'm doing a regular Google search and I'd like to see old entries from a particular website).

I'm running the latest version of Chrome on OS X 10.11.2. The extensions I use are Adblock Plus, Ghostery, Google Translate, HTTPS Everywhere and WOT.

Comment: Are you sure that a different browser displays the same site (or the date) in a different manner?

Comment: I just tried and the format I see is "Dec 15, 2015". Is every other news story's date formatted like that?

Comment: +1 Ben's idea - try opening the exact same url in different browser & compare. A web page should (generally) look the same

Comment: @Ben: I just tried under Safari. Exact same result. I use some of the aforementioned extensions in Safari but I turned them off just to check and once again, same exact incorrect spacing.

Comment: You should also check the real HTML content. I suspect the the server is sending the date in exactly this format.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a single website returning a weird date format, it might be just an issue with the web page.

Overall the settings you should keep in mind are:

- Chrome *Language* settings. Some websites change the date format depending on your preferred (or entire list of) language. You can find those here: chrome://settings/languages. If you're in the US, for example, you most likely just want that list to say (in order): English (United States), English.
- OS X Preferences > Language & Region settings

  - Check your list (and the order) of languages here.
  - Also go into Advanced > Dates and look at the date format option.